# How to get HTTP request details of a redirection page in Firebug?

Tags: firefox, firebug

For example, a typical login page will send a POST request to the server. Then the response includes a `Location` header and redirects to a different URL.

And in Firebug, the original login post request will just have a flash in the *Console* panel. Then the request is removed and new requests of the new URL are listed in the panel.

Is there a way to keep the original POST request in the Firebug *Console* panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirects can be tracked by Firebug by clicking the *Persist* button within the [*Console*](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_Panel) or the [*Net* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel) toolbar.

[image: Persist button within Net panel]

You'll probably need to persistently enable Firebug to see the requests for the redirected page. To do so right-click the Firebug icon within your browser toolbar and choose *On for All Web Pages* from the opening menu.

[image: On for All Web Pages option within the Firebug Start Button menu]

When you've done that, clear the *Console*/*Net* panel and access the redirection page again.